# relay-compiler 12 + graphql 16 = Invalid AST Node

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, relay, postgraphile

I have a react / express / postgraphile / relay project and recently upgraded all my packages to the latest to see what would break. I got through most bugs except this relay-compiler error `Invalid AST Node` which seems to be related to graphql 16. I down graded to v15 and everything works now, but I'm just curious if the bad blood is between relay-compiler and graphql or maybe in how postgraphile is generating my schema.sql?

**TL;DR**

Is relay-compiler 12 usable with graphql 16?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, relay-compiler is not yet ready to use graphql 16.

See https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/3622

Comment: Indeed: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/3622#issuecomment-961056263